# Shapefile filling

Tags: qgis, vectorization

[image]

I converted a raster into a shapefile. When I set no filling I see the contours of the different forms within the shapefile. When I set a filling, the whole file is filled, not only the shapes inside. Hope it is understandable.

How to do the set up that only the polygons within the file are filled?

Comment: looks like a polygon has been created to the extent of the raster.  Have you tried deleting that particular polygon? or do you intend to keep that?

Comment: No, I don´t wnat this polygon. I tried to delete it but it´s not possible. When I click to remove it disappears, but when pressing save it´s there again...

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to clarify what happens when you symbolize by ID or some other field. It unclear if your shapefile is corrupt or if your expectations are not in alignment with correct behavior.

Comment: Show us the screen where you set the styles. Even better if you could share the data.

Comment: How does the attribute table look like?

Comment: The Atribute-Table consists of 0 and 1 and in the end some "NULL"... more 1 than 0  :)  How can I share the data?

Comment: No one an idea?

Comment: Some time has passed since this was asked but you should run the geometry checker and validity checker against your new vector layer. Make sure there are no errors. I think there might be gaps in your polygons.